# build.xml does not exist when install zookeeper-client-c

Tags: installation, apache-zookeeper

I am newer to zookeeper,and want to learn zookeeper with c language.

I install **zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c([release-3.6.2](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/releases/tag/release-3.6.2) )** follow this steps to do. [README.](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/tree/master/zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c)

It occurs some problom when run **./configure**. listed as follow.

Why this problem occurs? How to solve it? Can anyone give some advices?

```
cong@pc:~/Program/zookeeper-release-3.6.2/zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c$ ./configure 
checking for doxygen... no
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for dot... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
.....
.....
configure: building with SSL support
checking for ./generated/zookeeper.jute.c... no
configure: error: jute files are missing! Please run "ant compile_jute" while in the zookeeper top level directory.
cong@pc:~/Program/zookeeper-release-3.6.2/zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c$ cd ../../
cong@pc:~/Program/zookeeper-release-3.6.2$ ant compile_jute
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
cong@pc:~/Program/zookeeper-release-3.6.2$
```

Answer (score 5):

The c**onfigure** hint is a bit outdated. I use this:
`cd zookeeper-release-3.6.2/zookeeper-jute/; mvn compile`

Comment: This would be better as a comment rather than an answer, since it doesn't answer the question directly.

Comment: @AlBlue The configure script suggests to run "ant compile_jute", but ant is not used anymore. It was switched to mvn and actually the required jute part can be generated with mentioned "mvn -pl zookeeper-jute compile" from ZooKeeper root directory and then run ./configure again.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood. Thanks for your clarification; I’ve upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The document in that path is really outdated...
I find the file "zookeeper-docs/src/main/resources/markdown/zookeeperProgrammers.md" is useful:

```
If you're building the client from a check-out from the Apache repository, follow the steps outlined below. If you're building from a project source package downloaded from apache, skip to step 3.

Run mvn compile in zookeeper-jute directory (.../trunk/zookeeper-jute). This will create a directory named "generated" under .../trunk/zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c.
Change directory to the*.../trunk/zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c* and run autoreconf -if to bootstrap autoconf, automake and libtool. Make sure you have autoconf version 2.59 or greater installed. Skip to step4.
If you are building from a project source package, unzip/untar the source tarball and cd to the* zookeeper-x.x.x/zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c* directory.
Run ./configure <your-options> to generate the makefile. Here are some of options the configure utility supports that can be useful in this step:
--enable-debug Enables optimization and enables debug info compiler options. (Disabled by default.)
--without-syncapi Disables Sync API support; zookeeper_mt library won't be built. (Enabled by default.)
--disable-static Do not build static libraries. (Enabled by default.)
--disable-shared Do not build shared libraries. (Enabled by default.) ######Note
See INSTALL for general information about running configure.

Run make or make   install to build the libraries and install them.
```